# AutoLayout Not Working

Tags: ios, autolayout

In my storyboard auto layout is producing this:

[image: result]

I wanted a result like this:

[image: this]

The problem this that the result I want is without auto layout.

Comment: What constraints do you have set?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to use autolayout, please reduce the pixel size of that color picker UIImage. Look like all other things are working.

Comment: The sizes are the same but when I run it the color picker gets a lot bigger as shown.

Comment: Not the size of your UIImage, check size of image added into project

Comment: Here is the link to the framework https://github.com/johankasperi/SwiftHSVColorPicker

Comment: have u added this line? 'let colorPicker = SwiftHSVColorPicker(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 400))'

Comment: Yes I have added the line.

Comment: I have just decided to make a viewcontroller for every device.I will keep the question open.